# xdebug stops at breakpoint but F10/F11 will not work

Tags: php, visual-studio-code, xdebug

I am new here with my first question:
I use xdebug with vs-code and wamp64. xdebug was working fine in the past but now I cannot use any single steps after hitting a breakpoint. Any ideas? Many thanks for your help!

Comment: Have you updated php recently? that could break

Comment: no, but after recreating the dir from git it is working again. \o/